# Problem with cxcore210.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying just a basic program with OpenCV with the following code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("give-back-to-society.jpg");
        cvNamedWindow("Image:",1);
        cvShowImage("Image:",img);

        cvWaitKey();
        cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
        cvReleaseImage(&img);

        return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get

The program can't start because cxcore210.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

However, I can see this DLL. It exists.it is added into my Sys-32 directory already.

I'm using visual studio 2010 ultimate.

sometimes, i get this error as well :

it says it cannot find the exe file.

what shld i do? any help?

Comment: any solutions to this qn? in need of help.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the dll to the application's working directory. That should at least provide a quick fix.

Also use this document for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Firstly thanks for replying, i did it but got another error: Unhandled exception at 0x7748b9bc in Testcv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003af708..

Comment: Make sure the image exists in the working directory too. Other than that, I can't think of any other reason for the program to throw an exception. Compiling in debug mode can also help.

Comment: What about surrounding your code in a try catch block? Print the exception message once you catch it. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem follow the below steps

1. Where ever you have the build path from cmake " build\bin\Debug " Delete all except the dlls
2. Now Copy these dlls into the Debug folder in your Visual Studio Project

Now Build the solution, This should work !

it worked for me :)